# Jenkins: Parameters disappear from pipeline job after running the job

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I've been trying to construct multiple jobs from a list and everything seems to be working as expected. But as soon as I execute the first build (which works correctly) the parameters in the job disappears. This is how I've constructed the `pipelineJob` for the project.

```
import javaposse.jobdsl.dsl.DslFactory

def repositories = [
        [
                id         : 'jenkins-test',
                name       : 'jenkins-test',
                displayName: 'Jenkins Test',
                repo       : 'ssh://<JENKINS_BASE_URL>/<PROJECT_SLUG>/jenkins-test.git'
        ]
]

DslFactory dslFactory = this as DslFactory

repositories.each { repository ->
    pipelineJob(repository.name) {
        parameters {
            stringParam("BRANCH", "master", "")
        }
        logRotator{
            numToKeep(30)
        }
        authenticationToken('<TOKEN_MATCHES_WITH_THE_BITBUCKET_POST_RECEIVE_HOOK>')
        displayName(repository.displayName)
        description("Builds deploy pipelines for ${repository.displayName}")
        definition {
            cpsScm {
                scm {
                    git {
                        branch('${BRANCH}')
                        remote {
                            url(repository.repo)
                            credentials('<CREDENTIAL_NAME>')
                        }
                        extensions {
                            localBranch('${BRANCH}')
                            wipeOutWorkspace()
                            cloneOptions {
                                noTags(false)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    scriptPath('Jenkinsfile)
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

After running the above script, all the required jobs are created successfully. But then once I build any job, the parameters disappear.

[image: parameters disappear]

After that when I run the seed job again, the job starts showing the parameter. I'm having a hard time figuring out where the problem is.

I've tried many things but nothing works. Would appreciate any help. Thanks.

Comment: Hi, I am also facing the same issue. Did you find the workaround?

Answer (score 0):

[This comment](https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-43758?focusedCommentId=357158&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-357158) helped me to figure out similar issue with my .groovy file:
I called `parameters` property *twice* (one at the node start and then tried to set other parameters in `if` block), so the latter has overwritten the initial parameters.

BTW, as per the comments in the linked ticket, it is an issue with both scripted and declarative pipelines.

**Fixed by providing all job parameters in each parameters call** - for the case with `if`s.

Though I don't see repeated calls in the code you've provided, please check the full groovy files for your jobs and add *all* parameters to *all* `parameters {}` blocks.